# string matching in query

Tags: xquery

```
<model>BMW, Merc, sakoda</model>
```

I need to check if the BMw is is model or not.

```
It is throwing me an error. Could you please tell me how to do it.
```

Comment: I don't know xquery, but the contains APPEARS to be missing a final ]  Also, posting the actual error message will help people who know xquery identify the problem...

Comment: try putting single or double quotes around BMW

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short, one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
xs:boolean(doc("car.xml")/car/model[contains(.,'BMW')])
```

This evaluates to `true()` or `false()` depending on whether there is an element:

`doc("car.xml")/car/model`

that contains the string 'BMW'

Comment: There is a typo in `contains()` function call.